# Update function does not delete all the desired data in real time database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have written a cloud function which is scheduled to run every 5 minute to delete the outdated data from the firebase real time database based on the timestamp field. (My data is really very big).

I manually checked and found that the function which I wrote is running properly and no error is shown in the console but some data (Not sure about all the nodes I want to delete as the data is really big) gets deleted from the GeoQuery branch (that is, data present at `"refxyz/All_Running_Buses/GeoQuery/" + child.val().id`  reference) but not from the Route_Ids branch (that is, the data present at `"refxyz/All_Running_Buses/Route_Ids/" + child.val().vehicle.trip.route_id + "/Buses/" + child.val().id`  reference).

May anybody please tell me what am I doing wrong?

**Here is what I wrote:-**

```
exports.deleteOutDatedGTFSRTPubSubAsiaSouthEastOne = functions.region('asia-southeast1').pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });

  const now = Date.now();
  const epochSeconds = Math.round(now / 1000);
  console.log("epoch milliseconds = " + now);

  try {

    const ref = db.ref('refxyz/All_Running_Buses/GeoQuery/');

    var cutoff = epochSeconds - 5 * 60;
    console.log("cutoff time = ", cutoff);
    var updates = {};
    var count = 0;
    const snapshot = await ref.orderByChild('vehicle/timestamp').endAt(cutoff).once('value');

    console.log("Number of Retrived childern = " + snapshot.numChildren());



    snapshot.forEach(child => {
      updates["refxyz/All_Running_Buses/GeoQuery/" + child.val().id] = null
      count++;
      updates["refxyz/All_Running_Buses/Route_Ids/" + child.val().vehicle.trip.route_id + "/Buses/"             + child.val().id] = null;
    });

    console.log("updates array size = ", Object.keys(updates).length);

    await db.ref().update(updates, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Error in update function = " + error.message);
      } else {
        console.log("Success in update function");
      }
    });

    console.log("deleted " + count + " nodes");
    console.log("Success");
    return null;


  } catch (error) {

    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    throw error;

  }

});
```

Here are some images of my data structure in real time database:

[image]
[image]
[image]